# Why is the plural form of attorney general "attorneys general" and not "attorney generals?"

Tags: grammar, government

As an example of this usage, here is a quote from a recent news item:

> Attorneys general in 11 U.S. states filed suit Friday against
> President Joe Biden's administration, challenging a new vaccine
> requirement for workers at large companies.

[11 states file suit against Biden COVID vaccine rule for private businesses](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/biden-covid-vaccine-mandate-states-lawsuit-businesses/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attorney_general#Etymology

Comment: See [State Attorney General's Office](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432414/state-attorneys-generals-offices/513361#513361) for the plural of the title. See [Addressing Attorneys General](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371104/addressing-attorneys-general) for the use of General/Generals as one form of *direct address*.

Comment: Are they fundamentally generals or are they attorneys?

Comment: When an adjective modifies a noun it usually comes directly before it: *a **big** elephant*. When the noun is plural the adjective doesn't change: *two **big** elephants*. However, some adjectives in English come *after* the nouns they modify. These are called "postpositive" adjectives: *a poet **laureate***, *the president **elect***. Another postpositive adjective is *general* in the sense used in the OP's example. Just like attributive adjectives, these do not inflect when the noun is plural: *these poets **laureate***, *previous presidents **elect***, *Attorneys **general***

Comment: They are the highest rank (General) of a part of the legal system (hence Attorney) of a US state or the federal system. See the link in my comment above-- this goes back to the year 1393 (vicar general). This is the  "rank" meaning of *general* and **not** the "non-specific" meaning as in *general counsel* (all legal matters)

Comment: @Jim fundamentally attorneys. *General* is a postpositive adjective here.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. -That was my point. :-)

Comment: @Jim Ah, I see! Ooops.

Comment: In court in the US they are addressed as *General* and not *Mr./Ms.*